# Comparison cloud function error words cant fit page

Tags: r, word-cloud

I'm working on sentiment analysis of a book i want to add a comparison.cloud output to my article but im getting "..." word can not fit in page error.

My code is as follows:

```
ftidy %>%
 inner_join(get_sentiments("bing")) %>%
 count(word, sentiment, sort= TRUE) %>%
 acast(word ~ sentiment, value.var = "n", fill = 0) %>%
 comparison.cloud(colors = c("gray15", "gray85"), max.words = 100)
```

Answer (score 1):

Reduce `scale`, `max.words`, and/or `title.size` in the `comparison.cloud()` arguments:

> scale     A vector of length 2 indicating the range of the size of the words.
> max.words     Maximum number of words to be plotted. least frequent terms dropped
> title.size     Size of document titles

Default values:

> ```
> comparison.cloud(term.matrix,scale=c(4,.5), max.words=300,
>    random.order=FALSE, rot.per=.1,
>    colors=brewer.pal(max(3,ncol(term.matrix)),"Dark2"),
>    use.r.layout=FALSE, title.size=3,
>    title.colors=NULL, match.colors=FALSE,
>    title.bg.colors="grey90", ...)
> ```

Source: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/wordcloud/versions/2.6/topics/comparison.cloud